# Can hyper-linked buttons in emails perform their function when clicked WITHOUT opening the browser and loading the page?

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, embed, html-email

I'm wondering if it's possible to have links embedded in an HTML templated email that would act in the background (once clicked) without actually opening the browser?

For example, when you receive an email from LinkedIn about a new connection request, you have the option to click "Accept" right in the email. Could I build something that would accept the "connect" when I clicked the button in the email *without* actually having LinkedIn/the web browser open and load the page up? [See image @ https://omniquadsecurityblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/real-linkedin-email-request.jpg for a visual]

I'd like to keep it completely peripheral/background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as of September 2015 you can not have an email perform an asynchronous action as you described. Email clients will remove any JavaScript you have in the message for security reasons.

The best you can do is what Linkedin does opening a new tab/window and sending the instructions with a GET request.

Comment: Thanks @JoeyPhillips . Seems like bad timing. Do you know what this act was called (if it was an act)? Or know of any good articles on the topic?

Comment: https://litmus.com/blog/ and https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/ are good resources. Litmus has a great podcast to if you're interested in email design. 

If you're more interested in web design and background processes it's referred to as asynchronous javascript (ajax) that allows you to do in browser actions. There are tons of frameworks that make it easier to use. Look-up bootstrap, ember.js, or angularjs.